# grouping dataframe by column with condition

Tags: pandas

there is my dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'name':["aa","aa","aa","bb","cc","cc"],
'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

I would like grouping by 'name' and values sum . Only 'name' column items having more than one occurence are selected . the new dataframe will contain 2 columns 'name' and 'total'

Desired output :

[image]

I tried this  :
(df[df.groupby(['name']).count() > 1].groupby(['name'])['value'].sum())
but didn't work . I got an error

Would be great to get a hint - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

make condition using [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) & aggregate

```
cond = df.groupby('name')['value'].transform('count') > 1
out = df[cond].groupby('name')['value'].sum().reset_index(name='total')
```

out

```
    name    total
0   aa      6
1   cc      11
```

Comment: I have an other question : 'total' column corresponds to the sum made from the 'value' column. But, if I had a 3rd column 'other_value' in my original dataframe, with numeric values ​​too, how to group by 'name' with sum column 'value' and sum column 'other_value'. The desired output will be : column 'name' , column 'total1' and column 'total2'. column "total1" for "value" and "total2" for "other_value". Thanks for your help

Comment: @sam `df[cond].groupby('name')[['value', 'other_value']].sum()`  and reset_index and change columns name

Comment: @PandaKim no need to select the columns and `reset_index`, use `.groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: @mozway I don't think others would have responded same answer as me. I think most people would assume that you would perform operations on two columns without indexing, given that there are only three columns and two target columns outside of the group.

Comment: @mozway Although this post only has one column, i also applies to indexing the `value` column. We provide answers in minimal examples, and i believe that unnecessary indexing is more valuable than not indexing and causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient approach would be to keep the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) rows, then [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
out = (df[df['name'].duplicated(keep=False)]
       .groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
       )
```

Alternatively, using [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
keep = (df['name'].value_counts()
        .loc[lambda s: s>1].index
        )

out = (df[df['name'].isin(keep)]
       .groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
       )
```

Output:

```
  name  value
0   aa      6
1   cc     11
```